# The file couldn't be opened because there is no such file

Tags: swift, csv, url

I'm new to Swift and trying to figure out how to import a CSV file into an array.  I can't seem to get it to work.

```swift
import SwiftUI

func getCSVData() -> Array<String> {
    do {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "http://www.rupert.id.au/resources/4000-most-common-english-words-csv.csv")
        let content = try String(contentsOf: url)
        let parsedCSV: [String] = content.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")[0] }
        return parsedCSV
    }
    catch {
        return [error.localizedDescription]
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var words2 = getCSVData()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text(words2[0])
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `URL(fileURLWithPath:` to `URL(string:`.

Comment: Also, never use `String(contentsOf:)` to load a remote file. Use `URLSession` to load remote data.

Comment: I would just use a parser library like [SwiftCSV](https://github.com/swiftcsv/SwiftCSV). Your example looks very similar to [the following article](https://medium.com/@deadbeef404/reading-a-csv-in-swift-7be7a20220c6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has multiple issues, such as:

Apple requires `https` connection. To use `http`, you need to set the "NSAppTransportSecurity" in your `Info.plist` to allow http connection to the server. Or you could use `https://.....`

Your `getCSVData()` should be an asynchronous function (look up what it means).
So you will not get anything in `var words2 = getCSVData()` because of that and because you cannot call the function where you do it.

Declare `@State var words: [String] = []`, so you can change this when the data comes,
see the basics of using `SwiftUI` and using `@State`.

To get the file from a server use `URL(string: ...)`
as mentioned in the comments. Note, you will get a warning if you just use this,
`.... Please switch to an asynchronous networking API such as URLSession`.
There are different ways to avoid this, the example code uses the `URLSession` as recommended.

Putting all this together and following the advice of the other comments, try this example code:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var words: [String] = []  // <--- here
    
    var body: some View {
        if words.count > 0 {
            Text("first word: \(words[0])").foregroundStyle(.red)
        }
        List(words, id: \.self){ word in
            Text(word)
        }
        .task {
            words = await getCSVData()  // <--- here
        }
    }
    
    func getCSVData() async -> [String] {  // <--- here
        // --- here, https
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.rupert.id.au/resources/4000-most-common-english-words-csv.csv") else {
            return ["Invalid URL"]
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            let content = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
            let parsedCSV: [String] = content.components(separatedBy: "\n").map{ $0.components(separatedBy: ",")[0] }
            return parsedCSV
        }
        catch {
            return [error.localizedDescription]
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: *"To get the file from a server use URL(string: ...) as mentioned in the comments"* - This is confusing. Creating a `URL` does not get anything from anywhere. The problem with the wrong `URL` initializer simply lead to a bad URL. The use of `String(contentsOf:)` is what was trying to get the file (from the bad URL). Your whole new paragraph seems to have confused the two into one. Sorry to keep pointing out issues but they're worth fixing.